# How can I use tellraw when a person's score goes up or down?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a scoreboard objective, EMERALDS, that automatically changes based on the number of emeralds in a player's inventory.

When a person gains/loses a point I want to display a `/tellraw` to the player saying "Gained/Lost An Emerald". How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a second objective and `scoreboard players operation`.

Create a second objective called `DIFF`

```
/scoreboard objectives add DIFF dummy
```

On a 20Hz. clock (fill clock or repeat/chain command blocks), run the following commands:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] DIFF -= @a[c=1] EMERALDS
/tellraw @a[score_DIFF=-1] [{"text":"You gained an emerald"}]
/tellraw @a[score_DIFF_min=1] [{"text":"You lost an emerald"}]
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] DIFF = @a[c=1] EMERALDS
```

To understand this, it's best to start with the last command. This command sets every player's DIFF score equal to their EMERALDS score. This means that at the beginning of each game tick, DIFF is the number of emeralds the player had in the *previous* game tick.

Now, the first command subtracts the *current* number of emeralds from the *previous* one, and stores that difference in DIFF. DIFF is therefore equal to the amount of emeralds the player has *less* than last tick, meaning a positive/negative DIFF score means the player has lost/gained emeralds.

In between the `scoreboard` commands, all we have are the two `tellraw` commands we want. One for gaining emeralds (DIFF ≤ −1) and one for losing emeralds (DIFF ≥ +1).

Comment: I modified the commands slightly, but this works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use the `/testfor` command like so:

```
/testfor @p[score_Emeralds=2,r=1000]
```

And you could testfor each score then connect the `/testfor` command to a comparator which would activate the `/tellraw` command.